# How should Task returning functions be called in the F# main method?

Tags: f#

The default template for an F# web API project has this main method (abbreviated here):

```ml
module Program =
    let exitCode = 0

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =

        let builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)

        builder.Services.AddControllers()

        let app = builder.Build()

        app.Run()

        exitCode
```

I'll need to make some calls to async code that returns `Task<T>` during this startup to get some config settings from an external system. I've come up with this potential solution so far including a mock `Task` returning function to call:

```ml
module Program =
    
    let getConfig (key:string) : Task<string> = task {
        do! Task.Delay 10 // Simulate work
        return $"{key}:123"
    }
    
    let exitCode = 0

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =
        task {
            
            let key = args[0]
            
            let! configValue = getConfig key
            
            let builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)

            builder.Services.AddControllers()

            let app = builder.Build()

            app.Run()
        } |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously

        exitCode
```

This at least compiles. I'm not very confident if this an optimal approach.

I'm I on the right track here, or is there a better way to handle this situation?

## Update

Based on Tomas' answer below I've simplified to this version which works fine and is much simpler.

```ml
module Program =
    
    let getConfig (key:string) : Task<string> = task {
        do! Task.Delay 10 // Simulate work
        return $"{key}:123"
    }
    
    let exitCode = 0

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =
        let key = args[0]
        
        let configValue = getConfig key |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
        
        printfn $"{configValue}"
        
        let builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)

        builder.Services.AddControllers()

        let app = builder.Build()

        exitCode
```

Comment: C# compiles async-main into `MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. You can do same thing: create *async main* and then call it from *regular main* waiting for task to complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much point in having the code `async` when all you need to do is to load some configuration at the start of the application, especially when you need to wait until it is loaded before doing anything else. In this case, you can just leave the configuration loading synchronous and it will make no difference, or (if it relies on async API), block to read it:

```
let configValue = getConfig(key).Result
```

Using `async` or `task` would make sense if you were then e.g. starting the application (while the configuration is loading) and only needed to access the configuration later (that way, you can start the app sooner). But if you need the configuration before doing anything, you do not need to do the loading asynchronously.

Comment: Very good point. Looks like I was trying to solve a non-problem :-) If I change the config function call to `let configValue = getConfig key |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously` that also seems to work fine.

Comment: I wrote this using `.Value`, which was wrong - I think `.Result` (edited) should work - it does exactly the same thing as `RunSynchronously` (arguably, it is a bit less explicit, so perhaps `RunSynchronously` has the benefit that someone reading the code in the future will see that there is blocking going on here).